# Laravel App Demo

Tags: laravel-5

Does anyone has any experience in next task:

I have ready project with some functionallity (some CRUD and payment functions)
I need to make something like demo mode. Where user can create records and make payments (always successfull, without taking charge), but it should not be recorded to database.
All entered data should be available only for this user and be live only fo
My question is how to make it without making copy of the controllers for fake actions?

I have try to look in to database driver that works with session as storage but have not found anything about it.